# hide elements after a certain value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

I have searched this pretty extensively and cannot seem to find the answer and I don't know if that is because it should not be done this way or I am doing it in a wrong way. I am just learning JavaScript and trying to build a counting game for my daughter. There are 21 horses in `div`s displayed on the page and I have 3 boxes that will have 3 possible choices for the correct number. In my JavaScript, I am able to generate a random number and want to use this as a benchmark. I am trying to iterate through the nodelist array and add a class to not display anything that is higher than the picked number. I have also used console.log everything I can think of to try to see where i am going wrong. I think my problem is I am struggling to tie the elements directly to the evaluation. I have tried a few different options so far. I don't know if what I am trying to do is just not possible with JavaScript or I am just overlooking the solution. please, any help is appreciated.

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Number Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="square">
        <p class="guess">
            
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <p class="guess">
            
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <p class="guess">
            
        </p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container horses">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/numbers.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript:

```js
    var horses = document.querySelectorAll(".horse")
    var pickedNumber = getRandomInt(22)
    var optionA = (pickedNumber + 2)
    var optionB = (pickedNumber - 1)
    var guess = document.querySelectorAll(".guess")



    init()

    function init(){
        getRandomInt();
        // numberOfHorses();
    }



    function numberOfHorses(){
        for (var i = 0; i < horses.length; i++){
            if(horses[i] < pickedNumber){
                console.log(horses[i])
            }
        }
    }



    function showHorses(num){
        if (num <= pickedNumber) {
            console.log(num)
        }
    }
        




    function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    };
```

```css
    body {
         background: url("cartoonFarm.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .square p {
        margin: 0;
        background: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }


    .square {
        width: 30%;
        border: red dashed 4px;
        background: white;
        padding-bottom: 30%;
        color: red;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 1.66%;
        border-radius: 25%;
        transition: background 0.6s;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
        -moz-transition: background 0.6s;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    @media(min-width: 768px) {
        .square {
            width:30%;
        }
    }

    .test {
        display: block;
    }

    .hide {
        display: none;
    }


    .horse {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 8px;

    }

    @media(min-width: 576px) {
        .horse {
            width:  60px;
            height: 60px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .horse {
            width:  75px;
            height: 75px;
            margin: 0 15px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        .horse {
            width:  100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0 20px;
        }
    }

    .horses{
        padding-top: 20%;
    }

    .container {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Number Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">
            <p class="guess">
                
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <p class="guess">
                
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <p class="guess">
                
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container horses">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


      

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/numbers.js"></script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

i dont think the css is relevant because i haven't gotten to that issue yet.

Comment: `if(horses[i] < pickedNumber)`. What is the value of each array element `horses[i]`? Comment the if line to discover it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question correct,  your goal is to show as many horses as the random int, and that the game is to count the number of horses and guess by clicking on the right number.

A good option is to add a css-class that hides an amount of horses. Use `horses[i].classList.add("hidden")` (and remove the class on all others, to be able to re-init after guessing). I rearranged you code a bit to not use global variables and to use more descriptive function names. But the key change is in your for-loop.

Also note the new cssclass:

```
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

```js
    
    function init(){
        var numberOfHorses = getRandomInt(22);

        hideOrShowHorses(numberOfHorses);
        setGuessingAlternatives(numberOfHorses)
    }

    function hideOrShowHorses(numberOfHorses){
        console.log("will display", numberOfHorses, "horses")
        var horses = document.querySelectorAll(".horse")

        for (var i = 0; i < horses.length; i++){
            if (i < numberOfHorses){
                horses[i].classList.remove("hidden")
            } else {
                horses[i].classList.add("hidden")
            }
        }
    }     

    function setGuessingAlternatives(numberOfHorses) {
        /* TBI */
        var optionA = (numberOfHorses + 2)
        var optionB = (numberOfHorses - 1)
        var guess = document.querySelectorAll(".guess")
    }     

    function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }

    init()
```

```css
    body {
         background: url("cartoonFarm.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    .square p {
        margin: 0;
        background: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }


    .square {
        width: 30%;
        border: red dashed 4px;
        background: white;
        padding-bottom: 30%;
        color: red;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 1.66%;
        border-radius: 25%;
        transition: background 0.6s;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
        -moz-transition: background 0.6s;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    @media(min-width: 768px) {
        .square {
            width:30%;
        }
    }

    .test {
        display: block;
    }

    .hide {
        display: none;
    }


    .horse {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 8px;

    }

    @media(min-width: 576px) {
        .horse {
            width:  60px;
            height: 60px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .horse {
            width:  75px;
            height: 75px;
            margin: 0 15px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        .horse {
            width:  100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0 20px;
        }
    }

    .horses{
        padding-top: 20%;
    }

    .container {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Number Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">
            <p class="guess">
                
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <p class="guess">
                
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <p class="guess">
                
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container horses">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="horse" src="assets/horse.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


      

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/numbers.js"></script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you so much this did it. can you explain to me what i was doing wrong or what i missed i am examining the code now but just so i can understand. thank you for your help this worked!

Comment: i think the main issue was your comparison `horses[i] < pickedNumber`, which compares a DOM node (`horses` is an list of nodes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) with number (`pickerNumber`). you only need to compare the iterator (`i`) with `pickedNumber`.

also you were lacking a way of hiding it, and css is absolutely ok for this purpose.